# Renaming duplicate list names in R

Tags: r, data.table, purrr, lubridate

Let's say that I have six data.tables that are contained in a two-level list as follows:
(Note - the values within the data.tables aren't important for the purpose of this exercise)

```
library(data.table)

DT_1 <- data.table(AA = 1)
DT_2 <- data.table(AB = 1)
DT_3 <- data.table(AC = 1)
DT_4 <- data.table(AD = 1)
DT_5 <- data.table(AE = 1)
DT_6 <- data.table(AF = 1)


# Create a list with two levels. The second layer contains the data.tables and may have 
# duplicate names both within each list and between lists

List_check <- list(A = list(X = DT_1,X = DT_2,Y = DT_3),
                   B = list(X = DT_4,Y = DT_5,Z = DT_6))
```

Essentially my code will create each of the data tables, and name them on the fly based on a timestamp in the format yyyymmddhhmmss.

The timestamp for the naming convention of the second list layer can't be more granular than seconds, so I'm finding that I'm coming up with duplicate names both within each list (e.g. we have two tables named "X" within list element A) and between lists (e.g. we have another table named "X" within list element B, as well as "Y" being a duplicate between lists A and B).

Also, the names of the top layer (A and B) can't be added to the names of the second layer of the list components (to potentially reduce duplicates). Other than that, I'm not constrained by having to have the list in two layers as all of the data tables are on the second layer of the list. Having said that, I must be able to know the relationship between the names of the top and second layer of the list as I need to save the second-layer tables to different folders later based on the values of A and B.

Ultimately, I want to rename all duplicate names in the second layer to make them unique, but still ensuring that they're in the required timestamp format.

For example, say that the names X, Y and Z referenced above were as follows:

```
library(lubridate)
X <- gsub("-|:| ","",dmy_hms("1/1/2023 9:00:00"))
Y <- gsub("-|:| ","",dmy_hms("1/1/2023 9:00:01"))
Z <- gsub("-|:| ","",dmy_hms("1/1/2023 9:00:02"))
```

We have three instances where a list table is named 'X'. My initial thinking was that I could simply add 1, 2,... seconds to the duplicates within each duplicate grouping, however that would then potentially create new duplicates.

e.g. As we have three instances where the name is 'X', I would need to rename the second and third as follows:

```
X_1 <- gsub("-|:| ","",dmy_hms("1/1/2023 9:00:01"))
X_2 <- gsub("-|:| ","",dmy_hms("1/1/2023 9:00:02"))
```

...however the problem is that X_1 = Y, and X_2 = Z so I've re-created duplicate names.

So my next view was that the pseudocode would be something like this:

1. Extract a data table containing two columns. Column 1 = names of the first layer, and Column 2 = names of the second layer. Something like this:

   ```
    List_names = data.table(Top_layer = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3)),
                           Bottom_layer = c("X","X","Y","X","Y","Z"))
   ```
2. Check if there are any duplicate values in "Bottom_layer"
3. If so, create a third column <New_name> which starts from the first value in the 'Bottom_layer' column, and adds 1s to each previous value.
4. Rename the original list with the new names based on the column 'New_name'

In practice, my data set will have many dozens of names in each layer.
The first problem I had was that I can't find a simple way to do step (1) other than looping through each of the names using lapply() for example, extracting each of the names of that layer and then rbindlist(ing) it at the end.
Steps (2) and (3) are pretty easy once I have Step (1) sorted.

Secondly, I can't think of a simple way to do Step (4) other than repeating Step (1) and looping through each of the names of the first layer and changing the layer 2 names.

But most importantly, I feel that there must be a better method than this! Potentially with some of the list functions within the 'purrr' package?

Apologies for the very long explanation, but can anyone a) think of a better way to do this, and/or b) help me with the code for my draft approach outlined above?

Thanks heaps in advance,
Phil

EDIT

I've added a more concrete example together with what the output is that I'm hoping for.

Firstly, I'll change the names of the List_check table to reflect timestamps as intended:

```
names(List_check$A) <- c(X,X,Y) #Where X and Y are defined as timestamps above
names(List_check$B) <- c(X,Y,Z)
```

To ensure that each are unique and to preserve the timestamp format of the names (in practice there's a character prefix, and then a timestamp - but for simplicity, just using a timestamp here), target output is such that the new list is:

```
List_check <- list(A = list(X1 = DT_1,X2 = DT_2,X3 = DT_3),
                   B = list(X4 = DT_4,X5 = DT_5,X6 = DT_6))
Where:
X1 <- gsub("-|:| ","",dmy_hms("1/1/2023 9:00:00"))
X2 <- gsub("-|:| ","",dmy_hms("1/1/2023 9:00:01"))
X3 <- gsub("-|:| ","",dmy_hms("1/1/2023 9:00:02"))
```

etc etc

```
X6 <- gsub("-|:| ","",dmy_hms("1/1/2023 9:00:05"))
```

In other words, if there is at least one duplicate, rename so that the timestamps increment by one second from the name of the first list element.

Please let me know if there are any questions.

Thanks again,
Phil

Comment: Perhaps you can use `make.unique` i.e. `library(purrr);imap(List_check, ~ setNames(.x, str_c(.y, make.unique(names(.x)))))`

Comment: Or if you want some more randomness `imap(List_check, ~ setNames(.x, str_c(.y, format(Sys.time() + rnorm(length(.x)), "%F_%T%OS8"), make.unique(names(.x)))))`

Comment: @akrun Thanks for that. It's a really good approach, however it doesn't conform to the naming convention that I need to work with (i.e. a YYYYMMDDYYMMSS timestamp - in practice with a character prefix immediately preceding it).

Can you please have another look at the edited example / target output that I've added above?
Thanks

Comment: @akrun 
If it can't easily be achieved using the method you outlined above, do you know how I can easily extract the names of each level of a list into a data.table as outlined in step 1 of the pseudocode mentioned above?
Thanks again

Comment: It is just that I didn't understand your requirement correctly.

Comment: Do you want `sapply(List_check, names)` or to make it unique `lapply(List_check, names) |> unlist()#
 A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3 
"X" "X" "Y" "X" "Y" "Z"`